# PyCharm SciView Not Displaying DataFrame Properly

Tags: python, dataframe, pycharm

[image]

So console is showing the correct precision for integers (no decimals), but SciView is not.

Is there a setting I can change? Because it is highly confusing when you're working with both integer columns and float columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a known PyCharm issue, please vote for the relevant ticket in the IDE's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39526

Comment: Oh god, not the voting system.... but I will vote. Since the data science community is much smaller than general programming. This issue will take a long time to fix.
It's sad.